# Get difference of time between min and max date on condition

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get the difference between first date and last date for a single id and put it on a new column.

say I have this df:

```
participant, test, createdOn
1, 10, 2020-04-09 19:38:00
1, 11, 2020-04-09 19:38:02
1, 12, 2020-04-09 19:50:02
...
2, 32, 2020-03-12 10:30:00
2, 33, 2020-03-12 10:40:44
2, 34, 2020-03-15 9:50:11
```

how can I get the time difference between the first and last test for each participant?

the end result can also be in a new df showing the participant and the difference.

I have tried like this `data_timestamp_diff = data_for_timestamp.groupby('healthCode')['createdOn'].diff()` but doesn't give me the result I want.

any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `apply` to find the time difference between last date (max) and the first date (min):

```
>>> df.groupby('participant')['createdOn'].apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
participant
1   0 days 00:12:02
2   2 days 23:20:11
Name: createdOn, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly:

try via `groupby()` and grab the first and last occurance by `nth()` and finally calculate the difference:

```
out=(df.groupby('participant',as_index=False).nth([0,-1])
       .assign(createdOn=lambda x:x['createdOn'].diff()))
```

OR

In 2 steps:

```
#df=df.sort_values(['participant','test'])
out=df.groupby('participant').nth([0,-1]).reset_index()
out['createdOn']=df['createdOn'].diff()
```

output of `out`:

```
   participant  test    createdOn
0   1           10      NaT
2   1           12      0 days 00:12:02
3   2           32     -29 days +14:39:58
5   2           34      2 days 23:20:11
```

Comment: This is more precise. First and last doesn't necessarily mean max and min.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
 df.groupby('healthCode')['createdOn'].apply(lambda days: days.max() - days.min())
```